Quarkus - Programmatically define Endpoints
We want to add programmatically created endpoints to our Quarkus application. As mentioned in Quarkus - Dynamically add / remove REST Endpoint at runtime not possible, there seams to be no way to do so on runtime. That's fine for us, on initiation would also work. How can we achieve that?
So fare I tried to find some Bean where the rest endpoints/path are registered and matched. But no luck.
EDIT (bad Solution):
After debugging the Quarkus (RESTEasy) routing I'm certain there is no way without patching RESTEasy. The solution for now is to handle the WebApplicationException, which is thrown when the requested resource/method can not be mached, in a ServerExceptionMapper and create the response there. I'm aware that this is not the way to go for multiple reasons.

in vert.x you can start/stop verticles (containing your endpoint) in runtime as you like. I don't know how exactly this can be done in quarkus though

If you want to do something like that, you need to drop down to the Vert.x level.
Something like the following would work:
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifecycleBean {

    @Inject Vertx vertx;
   

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
       router.get("/hello").handler(rc -> rc.response().end("hello"));
    }

}

See this for more details.

This can't work cause Quarkus uses unfortunately a own routing. It uses Vertx just to forward to it's own router mechanism.

I don't know why you think that, but it is absolutely not true.
